# Subscribe Observable and get Events of specific type

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, angular6, angular7

I have the following Angular service:

```
export class EventService {

  private subject = new Subject<Event>();

  send(code: EventCode, data?: any) {
    this.subject.next(event);
  }

  clear() {
    this.subject.next();
  }

  get(): Observable<Event> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }

}
```

Where Event and EventCode are:

```
export class Event {
  code: EventCode;
  data: any;
  constructor(code: EventCode, data?: any) {
    this.code = code;
    this.data = data;
  } 
} 

export enum EventCode {
  Created,
  Deleted,
  Updated
}
```

Then I use it as follows:

```
this.eventService.get().subscribe((event: Event) => { 
  // Do something 
});
```

I would like to be able to subscribe only Events with a specific `EventCode`.

Or maybe react only to Events with a specific `EventCode` ...

It this possible? How can I do this?

Comment: You can use a filter operator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before we get started, this:

```
this.eventService.get().subscribe((event: Event) => { 
  // Do something 
});
```

will leak memory when the component destroys because you don't unsubscribe. Do this instead.

```
export class MyComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  // store subscrition
  private eventServiceSubscription: Subscription;

  ngOnInit() {
        this.eventServiceSubscription = this.eventService.get().subscribe((event: Event) => {
          // check event code
          if(event.code === 'someEventCode') {
            // process event
           }
         });
   }

   ngOnDestroy() {
     this.eventServiceSubscription.unsubscribe();
   }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I have the unsubscribe. I omitting some code for simplicity. And yes, I also checked the event.code as you suggested. Probably I was not clear: I was trying to do something like `this.eventService.get(EventCode.Delete).subscribe(`. Just wondering if something like that is possible.

Comment: I mean, the EventService would be responsible for the filtering itself ...

Comment: You want a singleton service that emits `Foo` events to some components and `Bar` events to others? Use different subjects, and rewrite your `send` method to call `next` on the proper one.